# Confusing Boolean Expression

Tags: boolean

Given these values for the boolean variables `x`, `y`, and `z`:

```
x = true
y = false
z = true
```

Why does the following logical expression evaluate to `true`?

```
(x || !y) && (!x || z)
```

Comment: (true||true) && (false || true) is true So where do you have the problem ?

Comment: Should this be tagged as homework?

Comment: @DavidHoerster I don't think this is a homework problem. Even professors wouldn't give such simple problems :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitute in the values of `x`, `y`, and `z`:

```
(true || !false) && (!true || true)
```

Flip the negated values:

```
(true || true) && (false || true)
```

Replace the ORed statements (if one side is true, the whole statement is true):

```
true && true
```

Replace the ANDed statement (if both sides are true, the whole statement is true):

```
true
```

Answer (score 1):

True or False is always True. `true || false`
True and True is always True. `true && true`

Answer (score 0):

X is true in the first grouping causing the first grouping to be true. Z is true in the second grouping causing the second grouping to be true. Therefore group 1 and group 2 are true.

Answer (score -1):

```
(x || !y) && (!x || z)
= (T || !F) && (!T || T) <-- plug in x = T, y = F, z = T
= (T || T) && (F || T) <-- !F = T, !T = F
= T && T <- T || T = T, F || T = T
= T <- T && T = T
```

Actually, please tell us what's so confusing; I am slightly confused that you find it confusing at all.